# C++ set<struct>

Tags: c++, object, set, operator-overloading

I am solving a problem and need a custom set with special functions. The problem is I don't know how to implement them.

```
 struct S
    {
        int x;
        int freq;

        S(int X, int F)
        {
            x = X, freq = F;
        }
    };
    bool compare(const S &a, const S &b) 
    {
        if (a.freq != b.freq) return a.freq > b.freq;
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
    int main()
    {
        std::set<S> my_set;       //custom compare

        my_set.find(S(10, 11));   //find first element with x = 10
        my_set.insert(S(20, 30)); //normal insertion
        my_set.erase(S(20, 30));  //erase element with x = 20 && freq = 30

        cout << my_set.size() << endl;

    }
```

Comment: how about using a class instead of a struct

Comment: @Detonar They are effectively the same thing in C++.

Comment: `std::set<S> my_set;       //custom compare`there is no custom compare.

Comment: @Detonar What would that change exactly?

Comment: I suspect the question is about `my_set.find(S(10, 11));   //find first element with x = 10` ? Because that is the only thing where I think you've got a problem. That said, you don't want us to speculate what your question is. Just tell us directly.

Comment: Yes, I need to find the first element with x equal to some value.

Comment: As an aside, even when you've fixed your comparison as per the existing answers, you comparator still doesn't do what you asked for. To find the first element with `x = 10`, it still needs exactly the right `freq` value.

Answer (score 2):

The second template argument to `std::set` is a custom comparator functor:

```
std::set<S, compare> my_set;       //custom compare
```

To make this work, your comparator needs to be a type that implements `operator()` (the function call operator), which can be a simple struct like this:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(const S &a, const S &b) 
    {
        if (a.freq != b.freq) return a.freq > b.freq;
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::set<S>` by default uses `std::less<S>`, and you **are** allowed to specialize that:

```
namespace std {
  template <> struct less {
     bool operator()(const S &a, const S &b) { return compare(a,b); }
  };
}
```

(Or use a custom comparator, see Thomas' answer)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why specialize std::less<S> instead of [overloading operator<](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/946690b8a87d07f3) ?

Comment: @Borgleader: Feel free to add an answer - but the out-of-class `compare` suggested we're avoiding changes to the class.